# How to copy data from view and create new table in sql server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose I have to two tables, `Employees` and `Departments` - both are linked via pk and fk.

I have created a view `myview` and I want to trigger an event at 12:00 Am and  create a new table and copy data from the view into new table.

Comment: There are two question here. 1. What is the sql to do this? 2. How do I automate this so it happens every midnight? Which are you asking? Or both?

Comment: you should check `SQL Server Agent job` to schedule something you want to happen at certain time

Comment: problem solved via sql server agent

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is no table already, you can query directly into the table from the view with this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM YOURVIEW
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS ( 
    SELEC * 
    FROM myview 
)
```

Comment: No, not in SQL Server - this is invalid T-SQL syntax ...

Comment: Oh ok then. I'm sorry, I don't know how but I never saw SQL server in the above subject i just saw SQL.

the query above by @dfundako should do it though.